# dynamically add table row in HTML Table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
<body onload="LoadData()">
    <table id="myTable">
    </table>
</body>
```

And I have Javascript function like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadData()
    {
        var sTempTableRow='<tr><td>cell-1 </td><td>cell-2 </td><td>cell-3 </td><td>cell-4 </td></tr>'
        $('#myTable').append(sTempTableRow);
    }
</script>
```

I have tried numerous times and at all the times face an exception like `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected`.

Please tell me what is the problem here.

Comment: check your jquery js file is place in correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead if the onload event use jquery's ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      var sTempTableRow='<tr><td>cell-1 </td><td>cell-2 </td><td>cell-3 </td><td>cell-4 </td></tr>';
      $('#myTable').append(sTempTableRow);
    });
</script>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Mr. Kirill Ivlev .i can't user $(document).ready(function(){} because of i use it in a showmodaldialog window where i pass parameter when i user $(document).ready(function(){} function i face an exception like :                             $(document).ready(function () {
                var _oPerameter = window.dialogArguments;
                _oPI = _oPerameter.PI;
        debugger;
        RefreshPIProducts(_oPI.web_PIProducts);
    });  As a result i use onLoad function

Answer (score 0):

you can find the solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var sTempTableRow='<tr><td>cell-1 </td><td>cell-2 </td><td>cell-3 </td><td>cell-4 </td></tr>'
     $('#myTable').append(sTempTableRow);
    });
```

​and remove the onload statement.

You can find the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s8nZ5/).

Comment: Mr. Zakaria i can't user $(document).ready(function(){} because of i use it in a showmodaldialog window where i pass parameter when i user $(document).ready(function(){} function i face an exception like :                             $(document).ready(function () {
                var _oPerameter = window.dialogArguments;
                _oPI = _oPerameter.PI;
        debugger;
        RefreshPIProducts(_oPI.web_PIProducts);
    });  As a result i use onLoad function